# Script for decrypting/encrypting a file in Windows with gpg

Tags: windows, batch-file, encryption, gnupg

I use gpg for encrypting a file storing my passwords in Windows. This file is an MS Excel file, which I use for convenience. Every time I want to check or update my passwords (> once per day on average), I execute the following batch script, which decodes the encrypted file and encodes the updated xlsx file again when I close the application.

```
call  gpg --output pass.xlsx --decrypt  pass.xlsx.gpg
call "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe" pass.xlsx
call gpg --batch --yes --recipient myName --encrypt pass.xlsx
del pass.xlsx
```

Obviously, this is a suboptimal solution as it creates a decrypted file, which in case of an interruption (e.g. accidentally closing the command line window or a system crash), the file remains unencrypted. Anyone with something better, e.g. using in-memory pipes or the like (in Windows)?

Comment: The first thing you could do, is to remove all three `call` commands. Neither `gpg.exe`, or `excel.exe` are batch files, and so the `call` command has no purpose with them. Open a Command Prompt window, type `call /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, to see its help and usage information.

Comment: If you have a crash or the script/window is closed whilst the process is in action using memory as opposed to a temporary file, the decryption is still likely to fail too!

Comment: My concern is that after the decryption, the temporary unencrypted excel file may remain on the disk without me noticing it, e.g. because I accidentally closed the command line window (it happened!). Of course you are right Compo about `call`.